# Build up garage step

Tags: garage

The door from my garage into the house is located towards the back where there’s a 3” step up and into the house. Door is perpendicular to the step, but the door is 36” wide, and the step is only 20” wide, which means there’s this weird half-step leading into the house. Looks like the previous owner may have chipped up some of step as it’s very rough the entire length of the step up. Anyways, not too much of a big deal but just looks weird and I’d like to fix it. Any suggestions? Can I create a form and pour concrete on top of the existing concrete?[image]

Comment: Maybe the previous owner did not chip it.  It looks like timber under the sill to me.  You cant necessarily butt concrete to it.  Please clarify

Comment: I can't tell how thick it is from the photo, but I'm not certain plain concrete will be suitable here.  You might have better luck with a resin of some kind, if it's just gonna be covered up with a welcome mat.